# chai-http not exiting after running tests

Tags: mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I ran into a problem where my mocha tests were not finishing after running with chai-http. Mocha just hangs after the tests and eventually runs into a timeout (at least on my CI).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Turns out, Mocha (4.0) [changed their behavior](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http/issues/178) regarding the termination of the tests. The best workaround I have found is to add the `--exit` flag to the npm script to revert to pre-4.0 behaviour.

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server.js",
  "test": "mocha --exit"
},
...
```

Comment: This is just hiding the real error under the carpet. The reason for the hanging is a mishandled asynchronous call. Unfortunately mocha or chai don't really explicitly tell where the issue is, beyond which test file it is in - you'll need to turn off all tests in that file and turn them back on one by one to find where the freeze happens.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen According to the issue [response](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http/issues/178#issuecomment-336602457) on GitHub, the default was to force mocha to exit **after** the tests finished. This means the real error is not happening in the real productive code, but probably it's happening in the task runner. I can't change that behavior currently.